# TimeAt and Latest function not working on Kinesis data viewer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm just making a rest intergartion with kinesis and have created three data streams, it seems to be ingesting the data being sent find except

With the first data-stream named pin, I can view all the records sent by selecting the timeat function for the dataviewer just to see if i'm doing things right although for the other two streams, it comes up with no records but then when i take the sequence number and try search by that i can see the record that was placed inside the data-stream

I'm new to this and just wondering why that can be?